# Open a wordpress single post in a lightbox without the header and footer

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I am developing a plugin which requires to open a single wordpress post inside of a lightbox. Here are a few details :

- Currently,I am using colorbox for lightbox. The lightbox is triggered to open an external .php file which received the post id as $GET variable.
- Only the Title, Meta information, Content and comments part should open in the lightbox and not the theme header and footers.
- All the shortcodes , embedded youtube links etc should work in the opened post.
- It would be great if there is a way to pick up the current theme's single.php file, strip the header , sidebar and footer from it and display only the formatted content. But i believe that depends on themes and is not a generic solution

Here is the current plugin link :http://test.anshulsharma.in/

The current code for the external php file is :

```
if(!function_exists('get_post'))
{
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
}
$thepost = get_post($_GET["ID"]);
$thecontent = $thepost->post_content;
$thetitle = $thepost->post_title;
$thelink = get_permalink($_GET["ID"]);
?>
    <div id="cg-post-container" style="width:<?php echo get_cg_option('lightbox_width'); ?>px;">
    <div id="cg-post-title">
    <a href="<?php echo $thelink; ?>"><?php echo $thetitle; ?></a>
    </div>
    <div id="cg-post-content">  
            <?php echo $thecontent; ?>
    </div>          
</div>
```

In the current version of the plugin, only the posts content shows up. Shortcodes dont work and embeded links dont show up. Also there is no way to view or add comments. I am willing to write a custom single.php file for this and add my own styling . But i just want to know the BEST way to do it and also how to communicate the post id (from the $GET variable to the single.php) to the lightbox.

Comment: The problem with your shortcodes(and you'll have a problem with the title on multilingual blogs as well) not working is that you are echoing the content without filtering it. So instead of `$thecontent = $thepost->post_content;` you should have `$thecontent = apply_filters('the_content', $thepost->post_content);`. Instead of `$thetitle = $thepost->post_title;`, you should have `$thetitle = get_the_title($thepost->ID);`. You might also have issues with other plugins not working if you don't include the header and footer.php, because some plugins add scripts there.

Comment: The shortcodes are now being processed properly per your comment. Also, i want to include the wp_head event hook in the .php file (So that plugins that add some content in the head section can work) but this causes jquery to load twice (once on main page and once in the lightbox). This causes the lightbox to stop working.

Comment: You should then use an iframe in the lightbox, instead of just putting the content in there - will that be possible solution for you?

Answer (score 1):

If your external page is one precise page that is not changing all the time, your solution is easy. Create your page, let's say : `http://yoursite.com/yourpage`. Create a page template called `page-yourpage.php` (using the same prefix as the page name before `.php`) and in this template (that you can copy from `single.php`), just erase `get_header()` and `get_footer()` + add missing tags if needed (to close `body` and `html`). Call that page (`http://yoursite.com/yourpage`) with your lightbox link. All the shortcodes, etc. will work. Done. 
Otherwise, if you have access to the AJAX call, instead of calling the url, call a container inside. So instead of something like :

```
jQuery("#targetcontainer").load("/yourpage/");
```

call :

```
jQuery("#targetcontainer").load("/yourpage/ #sourcecontainer");
```